Sharepoint 2013 add-in equivalent in sp online
I am completely new to this. We have a Shapreoint 2013 Add-in developed already which has a list view similar to document library where user can do file operation(upload/create/delete) on the site itself.
I am trying to create a new SPFx webpart to mimic the same for SP online. Below are the problems I am facing :

The Add-in has a list provisioned and it get displayed and this list is not a part of site content. This list only appears when user clicks on the App and it gets open separately and user can play around. Whereas in new SPFx, we don't have an option to embed the list view on page.

The add-in is installed and it appears in site-content on sp-online. The SPFx app also appears but the list which is programmatically created in SPFx also gets listed in site content and user can click on list and play around.

The SPFx app in site content is not clickable whereas the Add-in is clickable. All the resources of Add-in(List and some other hidden) seems to be private to only the Add-in App.


Can someone please suggest what would be the appropriate way to develop new app which supports all the functionality of Add-in app?
